# Can I set the default package in java?

Tags: java

We know `java.lang` is the default package in java, and we don't need to import anything from them.

1. Is there any other package(s) like `java.lang` ?
2. Can I add another default package with the `java.lang` ?
3. Can I replace `java.lang` with any other package (I mean, If I
       re-write all the classes and interfaces from `java.lang` to
       `java.lang1`, then can I set `java.lang1` as default) ?
4. Can I change the base class (java.lang.Object) to some other class ?
5. If above listed things are possible where should I write code for that ? (Is that will be a java code snippet or some kind jvm or compiler specific code ?)

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just imagine (any of) that was possible, now imagine you download a Java program off the internet...do you know want to run it?  The `java*.*` package space is protected and the Java classloader won't load any classes from it...

Comment: You could write your own compiler (except for 4, which is probably impossible on the JVM).

Comment: You can use the command line argument `-Xbootclasspath` to override the default JDK classes (this is the option for Oracle JVMs).

Comment: Check this out regarding `bootclasspath`: http://www.tedneward.com/files/Papers/BootClasspath/BootClasspath.pdf

Comment: @Thilo - If he is writing his *own* compiler, he could as well copy everything (including the native calls) into a class called `Object1` and use it as default right?. I mean if there is a reverse dependency on the Java code from the native code, he will get into trouble with other classes as well. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind: By "write compiler" I meant still targeting the JVM. I don't think you can get objects to work on the JVM that don't inherit from java.lang.Object.

Comment: @Thilo - I still doubt if he could *successfully rewrite / copy* classes which make native calls. For example `Class` class can be instantiated only by the JVM.

Comment: `java.lang` is ***not*** the "default package". The "default package" is the package the classes in your sourcefile are assumed to be in if you don't use a package declaration in the file, which is "" (unnamed/blank).

Comment: @Boann : I get it man, I've already explained what in my point of view "default package" means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure enough that all of these are not possible to just post, "no, these are not possible." Note you can't do it with reflection since these are all compile-time questions.

(4), "can I change the default base class from Object," is not like the others, and is the most ludicrous. That would break many many programs at compile, because even doing something like `System.out.println(user)` relies on the fact that the object `user` has a `toString` method. In particular `String` is broken, because its `toString` method is inherited from `Object`.

Everything else you asked is compile-time only, so less ludicrous, but still not possible.

For completeness, it also would be strange and bad practice. I've heard of a C programmer who included `#define retrun return` in a headers file. So when any other developer maintaining his code saw `retrun eta;` they had to dig out the headers file to know what it meant. This is write-optimized code but software engineering is about read-optimizing code (yes I'm generalizing; trying to cover this in a paragraph). Cluttered imports do that - it makes it very obscure to tell where things come from, which is fine for `String` and `Exception`, but problematic even for things in `java.util`. Yes, this line was arbitrary at some point, but I feel it's intelligent and certainly should not include *more* things.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change your default package in java which is `java.lang` . All classes other than this package have to be imported using `import` statement. So for your `1,2 and 3` answer is no.

`Can I change the base class (java.lang.Object) to some other class ?` 
Answer is no again (atleast not in a simple way , without messing up with bootclasspath and stuff), and why would you want to do that. You can instead say `YourClass extends Object` and implement extra functionality and override existing ones, if needed. But even then all the classes would not implicitly extend from your class like they do from `Object` . The recommended way to use `Object` class is to override its method to implement your own functionality specific to your class (Like overriding `toString()`) .

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can.** But it is very very uncommon.

Theoretically you could do that easily, at run-time. Use the [Java Agent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to replace (wrap) the byte-code of the default Object class. And do the same for all class-loaders, where you need your custom functionality.

Note:

1. The Java Agent API might cost you about 10% of your run-time performance.
2. A JVM/JRE is usually certified to comply with the spec. Meaning, when you modify/replace a default class in your JVM distribution you might [loose support and/or your license to use the JRE (see "Xbootclasspath")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). You should verify that this type of JRE class modification is allowed in your individual case.

It's really not complicated. it's just another API.